# Can I add 2200µF capacitor to regulator 5V?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

Can I add a extra capacitor ceramic/electronic 2200 µF (actually working perfect from USB port laptop) for the test circuit for [L7805](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf) SMD? I need for peak current 2A [SIM800C](https://www.elecrow.com/download/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.02.pdf) module.

I don't know why they recommend 0.33 µF and 0.1 µF. Maybe somebody has a short answer.

[image]

I didn't include the complete schematic, but the system needs to work in 5V and SIM800C is fed by a regulator 3.8V.

Comment: I'm not sure the 7805 is the right part for the job. You need an input voltage at least 2V higher than the output voltage, which means your Vi needs to be 7V or more. If you are feeding it with 3.8V, you are below the drop out voltage and the regulator will shut off. It also can only supply 1A maximum, and even with the cap you may draw well over 1A.

Comment: I want to use two lithium 18560 3.7 volt in serie or some 9 volt battery maybe. The system works OK using a 1A cellphone charger adding a 2200uF electrolytic capacitor (I only have this)

Comment: @brhans I think the OP is saying that he wants to feed it from 2  18560s in series, 7.4V which will be OK for a 5 V output. However, as has been said, the 7805 can only deliver 1A. To get 2A you need an L78S05CV or similar or, as Marcus Müller suggests, a cheap switching (buck) regulator like [this one for 82p on UK Ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ADJUSTABLE-24V-TO-12V-5V-3V-DC-DC-BUCK-STEP-DOWN-POWER-SUPPLY-CONVERTER-SD/163799848759) . Other buck regulators are available.

Comment: I used this buck converter last Friday and the circuit died on a cold night in the garden, where my PCB was in a plastic food storage. I checked the converter's output voltage and randomly showed 8 volts while the set value was 5 volts. It was working all day correctly, but in the cold night :(.
I need the system working for two weeks inside a sewer... :D

Answer (score 3):

You can add the capacitor if you don't exceed the max power dissipation of the L7805. The L7805 is current limited, which means the low impedance of the capacitor won't kill it initially, if the temperature doesn't get too high in the part. This will depend on the input voltage.

Because typically a big capacitor will cause problems for the load. The L7805 can't source current instantly, the max short circuit peak current is 2.2A, so this is a source resistance of roughly 2.2Ω. This means the time constant with a 2200uF cap is 5 milliseconds which may be a problem if it takes that long to get to 60% of it's nominal voltage on startup for some applications.

It also means that the regulator needs to source ~2.2A (decreasing exponentially) while the capacitor charges, this may be too much power dissipation if there is a large voltage drop across the L7805.

Comment: 1000 uF maybe :S 3ms RC

Comment: It also depends on how long the cap would need to charge before it needed less than 2.2A so it wouldn't be purely exponential.

Comment: OKay I wil search for a tracopower or similar DC DC converter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the capacitor. The datasheet specifically says that the output capacitor is not required, but it does improve transient response. If you have a large transient (like a momentary 2A draw), the capacitor will help even out the dip from the regulator as it corrects. Since you are probably operating beyond the maximum for the 7805 I would say "designer beware" especially if you have a long transient draw. The regulator is probably going to get pretty hot.

The input capacitor is also not strictly required, but it is recommended if the input side is a long length from the input filter, **or if you have a large output capacitance**. The minimum suggested is 0.33uF, but in your case you may want to increase this. It should also be a tantalum or mylar cap with low impedance at high frequencies (as per the data sheet).

Answer (score 2):

> I need for peak current 2A SIM800C module.

Your 7805 seems to be rated for less than 2A.

So, pick a voltage regulator designed for the current you need.

> I want to use two lithium 18560

You're battery powered, so power efficiency should be of importance to you: The 7805, as a linear regulator, is undesirable because it converts the complete voltage drop from 2·3.7V = 7.4V to 5V at 2A to heat – that's a waste of 2.4V · 2A = 4.8W; or: 40% of what you use to power the device in that situation.

Thus, any linear regulator like the 7805 will get hot.

Use a switch-mode power supply instead. 2200µF capacitors aren't free, so for the price difference, you could buy a cheap switching regulator that wastes a lot less power and could sustain the 2A.

Comment: I used step up converter and in cold temperature the voltage was above 5V and the microcontroller and sim800c died :(

Comment: then you designed it incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think so, the system needs 5 volts because the sensor works at this voltage. The buck converter works fine.The problem appears when you put the electronic system at low temperatures near. The buck converter began to generate a higher voltage than the adjusted one, causing the components to die. I used a porwerbank samsung P1100BSNGIN before but it also failed, at low temperatures it generates an error message and the power is blocked.

Comment: so, when the converter starts behaving erratically at a temperature it should have worked correctly, it's defective or wrongly designed.

Comment: is it a good idea to use TPS62143 ?

Answer (score 0):

Some LDOs will overheat, as they try to charge up a large capacitor, and then SHUTDOWN for a period of time so the silicon die can cool down.